# Can a Big Muff Pi With Tone Wicker maintain middle tones and be the only fuzz/distortion pedal on a board?

Tags: electric-guitar, technique, effects-pedal

**Background**

I've recently started a band, we are a drummer, a bassist, and me on electric guitar. I am new to using electric guitar and effects pedals, previously I've mainly used acoustic by myself.

I have a Big Muff Pi With Tone Wicker, and I set the volume to a similar level to the volume when the Big Muff is off, so when I turn it on or off my volume should be similar. However, sometimes if I'm doing lead rather than rhythm, I use a volume boost pedal too.

**My question**

I was told after our first gig that when I turned on my Big Muff the middle tones were being lost, and my sound was being drowned out, which is common for Big Muff. (Whether this could have been rectified by using my volume boost pedal better, I'm not sure.) One suggestion though was I could buy a pedal like an OCD as an easy solution. However, I have a Big Muff Pi With Tone Wicker, which it appears is designed to rectify the issue (if you flick the Tone Bypass switch, I believe?)

What do people believe would be the best solution?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for opinions, which would be off topic. In the end, you have to decide if you're getting the tone you want. You can consider feedback from others but they aren't the ones playing guitar. What you really want to do is listen carefully for yourself and also ask your band mates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things that would help you situation

1. Increase the mid fequencies on your amplifier.
2. Buy a drive pedal that has a MID hump. Amplifier's, even with the MIDS at max, still have a HUGE mid dip because having no mid's provides a clearer tone with heaps of clarity. In fact the photo below is the fequency response of a fender amplifier with the mid's maxed! This is why it is good to use a pedal that increases the mid's a lot in order to stand out in the band. I would recommend a TS9, because it works well with both high and low gain situations. Most metal players use a TS9 so they can stand out in the mix.

   [image]

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKTm8YmwD7E) give live examples on two pedals, one with a mid scoop and another with a mid bump. You be the judge. Always remember that there is a HUGE difference between sounding good by yourself and sounding good in a band.